# What are the some best practices and patterns when implementing an ecommerce site using microservices?

Tags: e-commerce, microservices

I would like to understand from experience of others what are the best patterns to implement an e-commerce site using microservices?

Answer (score 0):

This [web site](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) has different kinds of microservice patterns for you to go through. It also uses a fictitious e-commerce application as the example to explain some of the patterns. Perhaps you will find it helpful.

Comment: May be a comment to the question, not an answer.